# How to install Kmean?

Tags: python-3.x, k-means

i already install pip,setup,wheel upgrade ..
but my error is

```
  Building wheel for KMeans (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1xlysuyb\\KMeans\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pyagyyuq --python-tag cp36:

  cl : 명령줄 error D8021 : '/Wno-error=declaration-after-statement' 숫자 인수가 잘못되었습니다.
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for KMeans
  Running setup.py clean for KMeans
Failed to build KMeans
Installing collected packages: KMeans
  Running setup.py install for KMeans ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1xlysuyb\\KMeans\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6c7xcoqh\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    cl : 명령줄 error D8021 : '/Wno-error=declaration-after-statement' 숫자 인수가 잘못되었습니다.
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1xlysuyb\\KMeans\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6c7xcoqh\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1xlysuyb\KMeans\
```

how can i fix it ??
i try upgrade setuptools,wheel, and my pip version is 19.0.1
what else can i try? 
My os is Window 10.

Comment: thank you see my error... i just want to install Kmean. if you okay, can you tell your email i will send all my error. i cannot post all my error in stack overflow

Comment: i don't know how to fix it, I asked for traceback because it will make it easier for someone else who might know how to fix it. In situations like this usually Visual Studio is to blame, I used to have similar problems with `mysqlclient`. Had to install 15gb of visual studio stuff to make it work. Here is a similar question, this might help you [Python kmeans package installation failure](//stackoverflow.com/q/50646462). Github issue about it https://github.com/numberoverzero/kmeans/issues/4 YOu can comment your errors on github, repo owner will help you.